# ContactForm not showing up in footer

Tags: html, django, forms, footer

I am trying to add a contact form in the footer of my base.html. Try tracking down everything I can but can't seem to find why the 3 fields in my form are not showing up. This is my codes:

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
    email_address = forms.EmailField(max_length = 150)
    message = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import CoollegeProductModel, NonCoollegeProductModel
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = "Website Inquiry"
            body = {
            'contact_name': form.cleaned_data['contact_name'],
            'email': form.cleaned_data['email_address'],
            'message': form.cleaned_data['message'],
            }
            message = "\n".join(body.values())

            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@example.com', ['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('product/home.html')

    form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, "product/contact.html", {'form':form})
```

contact.html

```
<!--Contact form-->
<div style="margin:80px">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
  <h4>Contact us directly if you have any questions</h4>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

base.html

```
  <footer style="background-color: #e3f2fd">
    {% include "product/contact.html" %}
  </footer>
```

This is what the footer display:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsUmY.png)

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: Are you sure you have your urls set up correctly. The picture you have attached is from `base.html` which includes `contact.html`. But the view you have posted is rendering `contact.html` directly.

Comment: Hi, Tim! In my url I have this path:                                         path('contact', views.contact, name='contact')                         with this if I go to local/contact/ directly, I can see the contact form working perfectly, but ideally I would want it to be displayed in the footer on every page. And that's why I write the include statement in the footer. Is there anything I am doing wrong there? Thanks!

Comment: if you want to include the form in every page, you need to make sure that every page has the form instance included in it's context. If this doesn't happen `{{ form.as_p }}` doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you will need to do to make this work correctly.

1. Include the form in the context of every page that uses the form (otherwise how would the DTL know what to render).
   e.g:

```
def view_that_uses_base(request):
    ...
    form = ContactForm
    return render(request, 'template_name.html', {'form':form})
```

2. Notice also that you will need to supply an action attribute to your form. Otherwise it will always POST back to your current URL (which will not have the logic to deal with that post), so you need to change your form to something like:

```
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'contact' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can just have the form in base.html so I don't have to do that many rendering? The idea is to have the contact form in the footer on every page, like the navbar.